# how to generate dbml file from Sybase database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

I think we may have trouble with our existing project. For some reasons we have to switch from SQL Server to Sybase SQL Anywhere 11. now we trying to find a way continue use our existing LINQ code.

We wish we can still use L2S? If cannot, we wish we can use L2E, then we have to change to ADO.

how to generate dbml file from Sybase Anywhere 11?  after that can we use sqlmetal to generate .cs files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to SQL only supports MS SQL Server. You might consider switching to Entity Framework if this is an option and if there is a provider fro Sybase SQL Anyware.

As far as I know there are also no plans to extend the Linq to SQL support to other databases, especially as MS pushes EF as the future database technology.